# array of lists - addresses within constructor and within main() do not match

Tags: c++, list

I tried to create an array of empty lists and then print the location of these lists from within main() and the Graph() constructor. But they do not match!!! Please Help!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list> // use list in STL

using namespace std;

struct Edge {

  int v, w;

  Edge(int v = -1, int w = 0) : v(v), w(w){}

};

class Graph {

  private:

    const int V; //number of vertices

    int E; //number of edges

    list<Edge>* adj[];//adjacency list

  public:

    Graph(int N):V(N){ //create a graph with no edges

      E = 0; list<Edge>* adj[V];

      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        adj[i] = new list<Edge>();

        cout << "at " << i <<" address "<< adj[i] <<"\n";

      }

    }

   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Graph& G);

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Graph& G){

  out << "Vertices: "<< G.V <<" and Edges: "<< G.E <<"\n" << "The adjacency list:\n";

  for(int i = 0; i < G.V; i++){

    out << "vertex "<< i << ":"<< G.adj[i] <<" -> zero\n";

  }

  return out;

}

int main() {

  Graph* G = new Graph(50);

  cout << *G;

}
```

Comment: What do you expect with this definition: `list<Edge>* adj[];`?

Comment: `E = 0; list<Edge>* adj[V];` You are creating a local variable here.

Comment: Failed to include output.  You have code where you have two statements on one line, and that is the line where you have a bug.  Your method shadows a class member, passing `-Wall` to the compiler would have given you a warning what you did wrong.

Comment: Try `Graph(int N) :V(N), adj{new list<Edge>[V]} { ` and remove `list<Edge>* adj[V];` Just remember that you probably need some `delete`s to go with the `new`s

Comment: If you're using `std::list`, why are you not just simply using `std::vector<std::list>> adj;`?

Comment: @flatmouse g++ -std=c++11 graph.cpp -o graph.out 
graph.cpp: In constructor ‘Graph::Graph(int)’:
graph.cpp:20:45: error: too many initializers for ‘std::__cxx11::list<Edge>* [0]’
     Graph(int N):V(N), adj{new list<Edge>[V]}{ //create a graph with no edges

Comment: @user3057681 It seems to work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10afc04017d66543).

Comment: @user3057681 It might be cleaner to do away with all the `new`s. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28d476ebb64084f6).

Comment: sample output:

at 0 address 0xec3c40

at 1 address 0xec4070

at 2 address 0xec4090

at 3 address 0xec40b0

at 4 address 0xec40d0


vertex 0:0xec3c40 -> zero

vertex 1:0xec4070 -> zero

vertex 2:0xec4090 -> zero

vertex 3:0xec40b0 -> zero

vertex 4:0xec40d0 -> zero

Comment: Johnny Mopp, @flatmouse

Thanks.

changed to the following code. it worked.

Graph(int N):V(N){ 

      E = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        adj[i] = new list<Edge>(); 

       }

    }

    ~Graph(){

        for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)

          delete adj[i];

    }
 

sample output:

at 0 address 0xec3c40

at 1 address 0xec4070

at 2 address 0xec4090

at 3 address 0xec40b0

at 4 address 0xec40d0


vertex 0:0xec3c40 -> zero

vertex 1:0xec4070 -> zero

vertex 2:0xec4090 -> zero

vertex 3:0xec40b0 -> zero

Answer (score -2):

Johnny Mopp, flatmouse

Thanks.

changed to the following code. it worked.

Graph(int N):V(N){

```
  E = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

    adj[i] = new list<Edge>(); 

   }

}

~Graph(){

    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)

      delete adj[i];

}
```

sample output:

at 0 address 0xec3c40

at 1 address 0xec4070

at 2 address 0xec4090

at 3 address 0xec40b0

//

vertex 0:0xec3c40 -> zero

vertex 1:0xec4070 -> zero

vertex 2:0xec4090 -> zero

vertex 3:0xec40b0 -> zero

Comment: It only "works" because you have a toy `main` program.  Change `main` to something where you're assigning or copying `Graph` objects, and you will see memory leaks, double-free's, etc.  The `vector` solution that I mentioned and flatmouse suggested gets rid of those issues.